# Is the result of C_FUNLOC a scalar or an array?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to represent some Fortran subroutines as `c_funptr` (`void *`) to create a dictionary via the nice [fdict](https://github.com/zerothi/fdict) library. Following GCC docs [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/C_005fFUNLOC.html#C_005fFUNLOC) I attempted to call `c_funloc`. However gfortran seems to return a `c_funptr` array instead of a scalar value.

Is this a bug in a compiler or I'm missing something important?

Output from `gfortran -v`:

```
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-cet=auto
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (GCC)
```

I have also tried using ifort (version 19.0.2.187) and it gives the desired behavior (see below).

MWE:

```
! = minimum.f90 =
module test
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    interface test_funptr
        module procedure test_funptr0
        module procedure test_funptr1
    end interface test_funptr
contains
    subroutine test_funptr0(fp)
        type(c_funptr) :: fp
        write(*,*) "fp0!"
    end subroutine test_funptr0
    subroutine test_funptr1(fp)
        type(c_funptr), dimension(:) :: fp
        write(*,*) "fp1!", shape(fp)
    end subroutine test_funptr1

    function bar(x) result(y) bind(c)
        real(c_double) :: x
        real(c_double) :: y
        y = -x**2 + x + 1
    end function bar
end module test
program main
    use iso_c_binding
    use test
    implicit none

    call test_funptr(c_funloc(bar))
end program main
```

compiled with `gfortran minimum.f90 -o min`

Expected output everywhere:

```
fp0
```

Асtual behavior: `fp1` with zero shape for gfortran, `fp0` for Intel compiler.

Maybe I'm just missing a right option for gfortran?

Comment: @francescalus, thanks for fixing numerous mistakes. I don't have enough practice with those articles :).
 I have noticed that you changed, for example, fortran to Fortran and `c_funloc` in title to all caps. Is there any set of rules that I can follow, or it is just a sort of common sense to increase readability?

Comment: Capitals in titles are a mild convention: we can't use code markdown in titles so it's a way of saying "this programming thing".  "Fortran" rather than "fortran" is just the correct spelling of the language's name (once, shudder, "FORTRAN").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `c_funloc` of the intrinsic module `iso_c_binding` is specified by the Fortran standard to have as function result a scalar of type `c_funptr` (Fortran 2018, 18.2.3.5, similar in Fortran 2003 and Fortran 2008).

Having the function result an array is a violation of the Fortran standard when the program is itself conforming.

However, in this case gfortran is not providing an array function result: you can test this with something simple like

```
print*, SHAPE(C_FUNLOC(bar))
```

Instead, gfortran is failing to correctly resolve the generic procedure `test_funptr` to the specific `test_funptr0`.

Consider also the case

```
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_funptr, c_null_funptr
  use test, only : test_funptr, test_funptr1
  type(c_funptr) :: ptr = C_NULL_FUNPTR

  call test_funptr(ptr)
  call test_funptr1(ptr)
end
```

gfortran 8 resolves the generic incorrectly and allows the direct call to `test_funptr1`.

Comment: Thank you. It happens with NULL indeed. Is there any way to force gfortran to choose the right method? In theory, I can modify sources of a library and manually call these methods, but it is undesirable to use `d_kv_fp0(k,v)` for function pointers and `k .kv. v` for everything else..

Comment: I didn't do a thorough search of the GCC bug database, but I'd be surprised if a simple compile time option gave the correct behaviour.  Your best bet is to try a later compiler version and report the bug if necessary.

Comment: You want to test with `rank`.

Comment: @Steve, want do I want to test with `rank`?

Comment: @francescalus, a zero-size array has a shape of 0.  If you test with `rank` you'll see that gfortran seems to be producing a rank 1 array result for `c_funloc`.  So, technically gfortran is finding the right procedure through the generic interface.  But, it gets rather odd.  If I comment out all code related to test_funptr1, gfortran produces a correct call to test_funptr0  and the rank of fp is 0!  Rather strange bug.

Comment: @Steve, I can't use `rank` to determine the shape of the result of `c_funloc` because `rank` requires a data object as argument.  Using the `shape` approach as in the answer I see a scalar result.  But the generic resolution is incorrect regardless of `c_funloc`'s result shape as shown by the example with scalar variable.

Comment: @Steve, if you're happy searching/adding to GCC bugzilla, then please do.

Comment: @Steve, yes `rank` with the dummy argument is valid, but that tells us little: if that procedure is called it's already gone wrong!  That `shape` has output "0" already tells us the argument is thought to have rank 1 - especially as `fp` is declared rank-1.

Comment: I have found a possible solution to the original problem -- storing function pointers in `fdict`, using one-element arrays of `c_funptr`. Actually, it has little connection with declared question title, so I'm in doubt. Is it appropriate to post it as a separate answer?

Comment: @taxus0c, workarounds for when compilers do wrong things with valid code can form acceptable answers.

Answer (score 0):

I will try summarize the discussion (to some extent) and address the original problem -- populating a dictionary from [fdict](https://github.com/zerothi/fdict) with function pointers. This dictionary supports multiple value types, including `c_funptr`.

It seems sensible to convert Fortran procedures to `type(c_funptr)` via `с_funloc` and append to a dictionary. 
However, due to issue in gfortran, a wrong subroutine is called and function pointers are stored as `type(c_funptr), dimension(:)`. An attempt to retrieve them as scalars results in Segmentation fault. To overcome it, you can create an array of function pointers, containing just a single element.
Something like this:

```
type(dictionary_t) :: fdict

fdict = ('bar' .kv. (/c_funloc(bar)/) ) //&
      & ('baz' .kv. (/c_funloc(baz)/) )
```

To retrieve a function back, you can can subscript a pointer array and convert it to fortran procedure pointer, as in the following snippet

```
type(c_funptr) :: cfp(1)
procedure(bar), pointer :: ffp => null()

call assign(cfp, dict, key) # generic from fdict
call c_f_procpointer(cfp(1), ffp)
```

Full source code with usage example may be found [here](http://vpaste.net/oAMNn).

This solution works with ifort, too. Both variants produce similar output with aforementioned example:

```
baz [fp1] (...) 
bar [fp1] (...)
  -1.000   1.000  -1.000
  -1.000  -2.000 -10.000
```